# Rails 3 - lost sessions between 2 requests from iOS 7 even with GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, session

Since a few days, I have a problem on my prod server.
Rails 3.0.20 seems to lose sessions between 2 JSON requests coming from an iPhone.

The login is OK, I can see it in logs.

But the next method called 'pull' has no session !

```
Started GET "/w/services/pull" for 109.1.101.218 at Tue Sep 24 10:12:43 +0000 2013
  Processing by ServicesController#pull as JSON
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"w"}

USER_AGENT
app/2.1.1 (iphone; ios 7.0.1; scale/2.00)
SESSION
```

As you can see, the session is empty in this method below:

```
  def user_required!
    logger.info "SESSION"
    logger.info session[:user_id]

    return true if session[:user_id]
    return redirect_to(:controller => "/users", :action => "login")
  end
```

I didn't know why for some users, the session is not kept between 2 requests.
I tried to disable **protect_from_forgery** but the problem is the same (and in my case the second request is a GET...).

I put all my log levels at debug, and I have no more info.

---

EDIT: Using logs times on the server, I went to see sessions table.
I can see that sessions that were lost looks "shortened".

A normal session data:

> BAh7ByIMdXNlcl9pZGkCZiwiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuIjFPKzdReDd3bHpWcjl6
>   SGRNNW1NMk4wNjZOYTJEU0R6MmlxdGxDMWRXM25B==

A session that seems to have a problem (shorter):

> BAh7BjoMdXNlcl9pZGkCThU==

Maybe it could be the origin of the problem...

---

EDIT 2: The _csrf_token is not created into the second session data example but I don't know why.

Comment: How are your sessions stored? Are you using Memcached? Once, I had the problem that I lost my sessions, because they got too big for memcached (default settings).

Comment: Hi Bjoersen. I used ActiveRecordStore. I didn't used Memcached.

Comment: I have edited my message to add more infos about the wrong sessions.

Comment: i would try having a look at the session cookie in your production requests. and another source of problems is SSL, is there any involved?

Comment: You are right phoet. The problem seems to be with safari cookies set to off on iPad and iPhone under iOS 7. Maybe I need to send the session_id each time on my webservices requests ?

Comment: Well, this is the solution: http://www.inmite.eu/en/blog/20130928-cookies-on-ios7-can-not-login